# Can I Invoke the available Win32 subset in a Metro style based app from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx
shows the subset of Win32 / COM that can still be used in a Metro style based application.

If you're developing in C++ you can simply call the methods like that. In C# you would use PInvoke.. but what are you doing as a JavaScript developer? Do you have to write a C# or C++ WinRT Component which wraps the method in question for you or is there a direct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write a C++ WinRT component which wraps the method in question.  Windows runtime APIs are directly callable from javascript but native APIs are not (there is no metadata which describes the native API so Javascript doesn't know how to call into it).

Fortunately this is pretty straightforward to do from visual studio - simply add a winrt C++ component to your solution and run your code in there.